# Angular - How do I cancel a Route Change triggered from the Back button?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my application I want to show a prompt message box or a modal whenever the user hits back button. I am able to use onPopState event but it doesn't prevent the user from navigating backwards. So far, I have this:

```
    window.onpopstate = (event) => 
      event.preventDefault();
      this.modal.showModal();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i do it in my app.

Import angular's 'Location' API in your module.

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

Add it to the provider's list

```
providers: [ Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy},  ... ]
```

Note - you may not need the 'PathLocatioStrategy' part of that if you're not rewriting URLs manually.

Then in your root component, or a singleton service, import Location again...

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

inject it into the constructor

```
constructor (private location: Location) {  ....
```

Then subscribe to the 'back' PopStateEvent.

```
location.subscribe((back: PopStateEvent) => {
    ... your code here ...
     this.modal.showModal();
});
```

If you're using the Angular router or anything else that uses the Angular Location API and path-rewriting, it may prevent this from working. I don't use the Angular router much but I'm guessing it probably has a method for dealing with PopStateEvents.

Comment: It works exactly what I had already. It does show me that modal pop up, but it also goes back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2/4 provides a way to do just the same. And the solution is canDeactivate.

**canDeactivate** is a route property that can be added to the route whose component contains the back button.

The canDeactivate guard takes a service as an Input. The Service implements the **canDeactivate** Interface(@angular/router).

```
{
path: "<some path>", component: BackButtonComponent, canDeactivate:[nameOfService]
}
```

If only this service returns true, the the user would be allowed to go back.

Further Reading: https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes

Comment: I will have to implement this in all of my components. I want to add single function in app.component so that anywhere in my application if user clicks back, modal should come up. Thanks!

Comment: Is the back button same for all screens of your app(The button is part of the shell) or does it changes?

Comment: It's same for all the screens. Basically, in my application, at any point if user hits back button, a modal should pop.

Comment: Then you need not use the canDeactivate. You can simply open a Bootstrap Modal whenever the user clicks the button. Then Based on the Action on the Modal you can go Back or do something else.

Comment: How would you detect with 'canDeactivate' that route change was triggered by back button?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the window object, you should use a route guard. In your route configuration, you should add a CanDeactivate guard. [Follow this guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes), it is very similar to what you want to accomplish.